# Why is program giving NameError even after defining function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to bind a function to open a new window with form to fill details with a 'Register' button. But even after defining the register() function, it gives NameError when I click the button.

Tried with:
1) 'command=function" method
2) btn.bind() method 
Still giving error.

```py
register_btn = Button(main_screen,text = "Register", bg = "grey",width = "30", height = "2")
register_btn.pack()
register_btn.bind("<Button-1>", register)

#function
def register(event):
---
```

Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'register' is not defined

Comment: define the function before you bind it. So define it above the bind.

Comment: Questions like this require that they come with a [mcve]. You probably would have found the answer yourself that way. As a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the function before you actually call it, unless you're using classes of course.

```
#function
def register(event):
    pass

register_btn = Button(main_screen,text = "Register", bg = "grey",width = "30", height = "2")
register_btn.pack()
register_btn.bind("<Button-1>", register)
```

Comment: Thank you mate. Problem solved. Didn't knew I was making such a noob mistake.

Comment: Don't worry about it, we've all been there, would you mind accepting the answer as correct though? I would really appreciate it. @NeerajRawat

Comment: *"You need to define the function before you actually call it, unless you're using classes"* Huh? Classes are not an exception to this rule.

Comment: No I meant you can call one class method from another method in the same class no matter where it is defined, whether it's way up or way down. @Aran-Fey get what I am saying?

Comment: @Sahil Just like you can call a function from another function, no matter where it is defined.